# Cannot validate user input correctly from server?

Tags: javascript, php, html

How do I check multiple variable inputs at once to ensure that the regex is working? Everytime I enter anything, the form submits and doesn't alert anything.

I have tried test()method of regex validation too, and still no luck.

I am trying to validate user input with the following regex that makes to where anything that is **not a number or blank space** is considered a wrong input.

```
var format=/^(\s*|\d+)$/;
```

It only accepts numbers and blank spaces in the text box.

The following javascript is what I have:

```js
var pitch = document.getElementById("pitch");
var chisel = document.getElementById("chis");
var saw = document.getElementById("saw");

//var arguments = [chisel, saw, pitch];

var format = /^(\s*|\d+)$/;

function regexTest() {
  if (!chisel.match(format) && !saw.match(format) && !pitch.match(format)) {
    alert("Repressed Action");
    return false;
  } else {
    alert('Thank you');
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="lab">

  <form method="post" action="http://weblab.kennesaw.edu/formtest.php">
    Chisels: <input type="text" name="chisels" id="chis" size="5" /> Saw: <input type="text" name="saw" id="saw" size="5" /> Pitchfork: <input type="text" name="pitchfork" id="pitch" size="5" />

    <br /> Customer Name: <input type="text" name="customer name" size="25" />
    <br /> Shipping Address: <input type="text" name="shipping address" size="25" />
    <br /> State:
    <input type="radio" id="master" name="card" value="master" /><label for="master">MasterCard</label>
    <input type="radio" id="american" name="card" value="american" /><label for="american">American Express</label>
    <input type="radio" id="visa" name="card" value="visa" /><label for="visa">Visa</label>

    <br />

    <input type="reset" value="Reset" />

    <div class="lab">
      <button onclick="regexTest()">Submit</button>
      <button onclick="return false">Cancel</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: Seems to me the regular expression should be `/[^\s\d]/`, which will match anything that isn't a digit or space. And if you're going to post HTML, don't include PHP, post actual runnable code.

Comment: @RobG I believe your solution was correct.

Comment: It works partially. If I have all three inputs as numbers, it works. However if I make one of them a letter, it still works. I will keep trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of issues with your code, below I've refactored it to be a bit easier to read and so it works.

The validation listener should be on the form's submit handler, not the submit button since forms can be submitted without clicking the button. Also, if you pass a reference to the form to the listener, it's much easier to access the form controls by name.

You should get the values of the form controls when the submit occurs, not before. Your code gets the values immediately, before the user has done anything (and possibly before the form even exists), so put that code inside the listener function.

Lastly, the regular expression needs to match anything that isn't a space or digit, so:

```
/[^\s\d]/
```

seems appropriate. However, this will still allow the form to submit if the fields are empty (they don't contain non-digits or non-spaces). You'll need to add a test for that.

```js
function regexTest(form) {
  // Get values when the function is called, not before
  var pitch = form.pitchfork.value;
  var chisel = form.chisels.value;
  var saw = form.saw.value;

  // Test for anything that's not a space or digit      
  //  var format = /^(\s*|\d+)$/;
  var format = /[^\s\d]/;

  if (format.test(chisel) || format.test(pitch) || format.test(saw)) {
    // There must be at least one non-space or non-digit in a field
    alert("Repressed Action");
    return false;

  } else {
    alert('Thank you');
    // return false anyway for testing
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="lab">
  <form onsubmit="return regexTest(this)">
    Chisels: <input type="text" name="chisels" id="chis" size="5"><br>
    Saw: <input type="text" name="saw" id="saw" size="5"><br>
    Pitchfork: <input type="text" name="pitchfork" id="pitch" size="5"><br>
    Customer Name: <input type="text" name="customer name" size="25"><br>
    Shipping Address: <input type="text" name="shipping address" size="25">
    <br> State:
    <select name="states">
      <option>Florida</option>
      <option>Georgia</option>
      <option>Alabama</option>
   </select>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" id="master" name="card" value="master"><label for="master">MasterCard</label>
    <input type="radio" id="american" name="card" value="american"><label for="american">American Express</label>
    <input type="radio" id="visa" name="card" value="visa"><label for="visa">Visa</label>
    <br>
    <input type="reset" value="Reset">
    <div class="lab">
      <button>Submit</button>
      <button onclick="return false">Cancel</button>
    </div>
```

Hopefully this gets you to the next step.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I do must note that I have to keep the form to send to the php file on submission, so I have to change that <form onsubmit="return regexTest(this)"> back